# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnmR8.png)

I'm in college and new to coding. The professor is teaching us Java, but I keep encountering this error whenever I try running her code.

This is the second time I encounter this problem, and I spent so much time trying to solve it last time I don't even remember what I did. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what is the issue. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: An array of length `0` contains nothing.

Comment: You are not running this correctly. It expects three command line arguments, and you are providing none.

Comment: ohhh right!! idk how to do that on VSCode tho.. but thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great tutorial by Java, on the *exception* mechanism used within the framework.
*[What Is an Exception? (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential Java Classes > Exceptions)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html)*

The error you're encountering states the following.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at Programa01.main(Programa01.java:11)
```

This is caused by an *Exception* which was thrown by one of the statements.

The first line here, outlines the type of *Exception*, in this case an *[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)*.
Which is followed by a message—optional, although will sometimes includes relative information.

In this case it states the following.

> *Index 0 out of bounds for length 0*

Firstly, you'll need to determine how to locate the error.

The last line in the error includes the line-number of which the error occurred.
In this case it is line *11*, as denoted within the parentheses, after the *.java* file-extension.

```
at Programa01.main(Programa01.java:11)
```

If you look at line 11, you'll find the following code.

```java
NumInt = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

There are a few *[statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)* in this line.

Firstly, you have the *NumInt* assignment.

```java
NumInt =
```

Additionally, you have the *[Integer#parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))* method call.

```java
Integer.parseInt()
```

And, finally, you have the *args* array access.
In which your syntax is specifying a resolve to index *0*.

```java
args[0]
```

Since the *Exception* that was thrown is an *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException*, we can presume that the logic propagates from this final statement, the *args* array access.

Thus, index *0* of the *args* array is inaccessible, since the *length* of *args* is 0—it contains no elements.

The *args* parameter is an argument which is supplied and populated by the Java Virtual Machine upon the start of your program.

Here is a tutorial on *Command-Line Arguments*.
*[Command-Line Arguments (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential Java Classes > The Platform Environment)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)*.

Since you're using *VSCode*, you can refer to the following tutorial on adding *Launch Configurations*.
*[VisualStudio.com – Debugging in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations)*.

If you need more assistance on adding the values, feel free to leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass 3 arguments as your code expects them. Currently you're passing none. Since you're launching your code via VSCode IDE, try to add arguments via IDE:

Run -> Add Configuration...

It will open *launch.json* file. Add the line with arguments to the section where the mainClass specified:

```
"args": ["one","two","three"]
```

Consider adding the proper arguments as per your code's logic: *integer*, *double* & *string*.
Whole *launch.json* should be a valid JSON file, thus pls don't forget about commas and quotes around the arguments even if they are not strings. It should help, good luck.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)